# find "backend" command(s) executed by a frontend application on a SUSE LINUX ENTERPRISE SERVER 9 (kernel 2.6.5)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a frontend application that does several things on a menu based. One of its item is "backup database". Is there a way to find what exactly command(s) execute this. I am thinking of something like history in shell or looking somewhere in logs. I'm noob with linux so please be very precise.
Thanks in advance for answers !

Comment: Well, you *do* have the actual command called `history` in bash/shell. That'll show you the command history of the current user. You'd need to become the user you're interested in to see their command history. Eg. `sudo su` to become root and type `history` to see root's history. Remember to close the window or type `exit` afterwards (never stay in root longer than necessary - you might forget and do something dangerous). Other than that, you have all the logs in /var/log/ (syslog and auth.log can be particularly useful) and the command `dmesg` to show kernel messages

Comment: Yes I know about history command. But as I said the command is executed from a front end application, not from command shell....

Comment: Ok, have you checked out `lastcomm`, `sa` and the other tools in the `psacct` or `acct` package? On Ubuntu, it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install acct` so I would assume you can do `sudo zypper install psacct` or `sudo zypper install acct` on SUSE. It gets its information from the system-wide acct (account) file and not just the shell. I can't guarantee that your specific database actions will show up there but I would think so. I believe it logs anything that internally uses `exec` (this might *not* include specific shell built-ins like `cd`).

Comment: A few informative links: [here's](http://www.golinuxhub.com/2014/06/how-to-keep-track-of-all-commands-run.html) how to keep track of all commands run, [here's](http://pc-freak.net/blog/track-user-accounts-executed-commands/) a bunch of command examples for all your copy/paste needs :) and [here's](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-lastcomm-command-examples-usage-syntax/) some info on the `lastcomm` utility. And oh, you're actually in the wrong forum. The good people over at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) are the experts; this forum is for programming questions only.